# How to create HTML mail in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, html

I would like to send an HTML mail using Gmail.

Following

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/how-to/how-to-create-an-html-email-in-gmail/

I just copied my HTML into the message, but it did not work, Gmail shows the code but does not interpret it as HTML.

What should I do to make Gmail understand that this is HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gmass.co/blog/use-custom-html-in-gmail-compose-window/

Option 2:

> right-click anywhere in the Compose box and choose Inspect

This is Gmail's mail compose box. This leads to the HTML code of the web page, pointing to the div element of the mail under composition.

There with right-click on the element a menu comes up whose first entry is

> Edit as HTML

where you can insert your pre-written HTML code.

And this worked for me with Firefox.